# php вывод массива из json

Tags: php, javascript, html, json, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]сейчас я делаю вывод массива skills прямым выводом его элементов, но если в массиве элементов оказывается меньше трех - скрипт не работает, а если больше - они тоже не выводятся.
как сделать в цикле вывод всех элементов массива skills ?

```html
//JSON
{ "skills":[ {"option":"preferred","level":2,"id":159,"name":"Presentation skills"}, {"option":"preferred","level":1,"id":162,"name":"Language Teaching"}, {"option":"preferred","level":2,"id":161,"name":"Sales"} ]} 


//PHP
$url = "http://***";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$decoded = json_decode($content);

$s1name = $decoded->skills[0]->name;
$s2name = $decoded->skills[1]->name;
$s3name = $decoded->skills[2]->name;

echo sprintf('
<tr>
  <td class="headings"> Навыки </td>
  <td class="content">%s</td>
</tr>', $s1name); 

echo sprintf('
<tr>
  <td class="headings"> </td>
  <td class="content">%s</td>
</tr>', $s2name); 

echo sprintf('
<tr>
  <td class="headings"> </td>
  <td class="content">%s</td>
</tr>', $s3name); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы с массивом используйте циклы. Либо цикл [for](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.for.php), который позволит пройтись во всем элементам массива (их количество можно получить функцией [count](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.count.php), которую следует вычислить заранее:

```
$collectionSize = count($decoded);
for($i = 0; $i < $collectionSize; $i++){
    $item = $decoded[$i];
    echo sprintf('
        <tr>
        <td class="headings"> Навыки </td>
        <td class="content">%s</td>
        </tr>', $item->name);
}
```

Либо можно использовать цикл [foreach](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php), который сам вычисляет длину массива, а также позволяет обращаться к элементу массива через временную переменную.

```
foreach($decoded as $item){
    echo sprintf('
        <tr>
        <td class="headings"> Навыки </td>
        <td class="content">%s</td>
        </tr>', $item->name);
}
```

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in         </tr>', $item->name);

Comment: @NormalArs похоже, вы используете только мой фрагмент кода. Этот фрагмент лишь заменяет  ваши 3 вывода через ```echo``` и, если вам больше не понадобятся переменные ```$s1name```, ```$s2name```, ```$s3name```, то и их объявление

Comment: @NormalArs извиняюсь, не увидел, что массив наш не ```$decoded```, а ```$decoded->skills``` замените в моих примерах ```$decoded``` на ```$decoded->skills```

Comment: да) я уже разобрался, спасибо